configuring karrigell logging to log uncaught exceptions
I am managing a third-part app made with python's framework Karrigell.
I have added a new logger, my_logger, which is declared and instantiated in a file called my_logging.py
I see that the logger can properly fill the log file with messages
my_logger.info("message from my_logger.info")

However, it seems it cannot log tracebacks, nor of handled nor of unhandled exceptions.
Here are some scenarios:
In a html template file of my project, customer_file.hip, I have the following scenarios:
scenario 1 - syntax error
customer_file.hip
from my_logging import my_logger
import sys, traceback

...

try:    
    my_logger.info("my_logger.info - I am going to raise a exception inside a 'try' block.")
    hello, this line triggers a handled error

except Exception:
    my_logger.info("exception for file {}, name {}".format(__file__, __name__))
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr) 
    my_logger.info("Logged the exception traceback.")

result
the traceback is printed in the browser as I try to access the page rendered by my template, but not in my log file.

scenario 2 - unhandled exception
customer_file.hip
from my_logging import my_logger
import sys, traceback

...

my_logger.info("my_logger.info - I am going to raise an unhandled exception.")
new_variable = undeclared_variable
my_logger.info("this line of code is never reached.")

result
only I am going to raise an unhandled exception gets printed in my log file.
scenario 3 - handled exception
customer_file.hip
from my_logging import my_logger
import sys, traceback

...

try:    
    my_logger.info("my_logger.info - I am going to raise a exception inside a 'try' block.")
    new_variable = undeclared_variable
    my_logger.info("this line of code is never reached.")

except Exception:
    my_logger.info("exception for file {}, name {}".format(__file__, __name__))
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr) 
    my_logger.info("Logged the exception traceback.")

result
only I am going to raise a exception inside a 'try' block gets printed in my log file.

Here below is the code of my_logging.py, how can I change it to keep track of both handled and unhandled exceptions?
my_logging.py
import os
import datetime

import sys
import traceback

import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler


def setup_logger():

    ##############
    # stdout part
    ##############

    # log filename
    # --------------

    log_dir = "/home/myuser/var/log/my_project"
    log_filename = "my_project.log"
    log_file_path = os.path.join(log_dir, log_filename)


    # log directory
    # ---------------

    if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
        try:
            os.makedirs(log_dir)
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno != 17:  # Errno 17 = "File exists"
                raise  # raise exception if  the error is not "file exists"

    # logger name
    # --------------
    logger_1 = logging.getLogger("my_project_logger")


    # logger level
    # --------------
    logger_1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # logger's level (DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL)


    # Formatter
    # -----------

    formatter_1 = logging.Formatter(
        "[%(asctime)s %(name)s]  %(message)s"
        # %(levelname)s
    )


    # File handler
    # --------------

    # define a rotating File Handler
    file_handler_1 = TimedRotatingFileHandler(
        log_file_path, 
        when="midnight", 
        interval=1, 
        backupCount=7
    )

    return logger_1

# instantiate the logger

my_logger = setup_logger()

what I have tried
I have tried to add a global handler for uncaught expressions:
in my_logging.py, at the end, after line
my_logger = setup_logger()

I have added
def handle_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    if issubclass(exc_type, KeyboardInterrupt):
        sys.__excepthook__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
        return
    my_logger.error("Uncaught exception", exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))

sys.excepthook = handle_exception

but the error message does not get logged.
